# Handling models out of screen libgdx

Tags: opengl, libgdx

In libgdx 2d we used to not render sprites that aren't inside the screen, however in 3d from what I have read you draw a whole scene as the level, my scene is pretty big, I was wondering if im suppose to handle models that are out of the screen? and how?

Comment: I don't understand the question. It's up to you whether you think it's worth filtering out the drawing of items that aren't in view or not. It depends on the complexity of the scene. This same principle applies to 2D or 3D. 3D meshes are obviously much heavier objects than sprites, so you are more likely to want to skip drawing ones that aren't in view.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I guess my question is,  a scene is one big model, so u either draw it or you don't, but most of the model(scene) is going to be out of the screen. So how I handle that? do I some how have to delete vertices that are out of screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really practical to rebuild a mesh to hide certain vertices. You would have to micromanage the building of your mesh and make sure you don't hide vertices that are part of triangles that are still visible. And you'd have to very carefully rebuild your indices array. In most cases this would be completely infeasible because you are probably building your mesh in a modeling program.

Your options are to model your scene as multiple separate models, or to not worry about it. It depends on the complexity which makes more sense.

If you have separate model meshes, you could calculate bounding boxes for them and then test them with `camera.frustum.boundsInFrustum()` to decide whether they should be drawn.

Note that vertices drawn outside the camera frustum only cost you some wasted vertex shader calculations, not fragment shader calculations. At a certain point, the savings you get by skipping some vertices will be eaten up by the cost of calculating which vertices you don't need to draw.